# Swift Firebase Auth Error Identification

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
            if error == nil{
                user?.sendEmailVerification(completion: nil)


            }else if error == ?!?!?!{
                //alert user of issue

            }
```

I have a swift app with an authentication page for users to sign in/create an account using the create account callback above. Everything works fine if there are no errors returned. However, if there are errors returned I cannot figure out how to identify the error type to take the proper actions. For example, if the user tries to sign up using an email that is already taken I know Firebase will return a 'FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse' but how can I read that in a meaningful way to notify the user that that email is already used?

Comment: "It looks like somebody already signed up with this email address. If you lost access to your account, click here to reset your password." (with of course an actual password reset link in there).

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(error?.localizedDescription)
```

Comment: Yes, I can print the error to the console but that doesn't help the user to understand what the problem is.  I need to be able to send a message to the user based on what type of error is occurring, which requires the program to recognize what type of error is occuring.

Comment: What does that print out for you? You can copy the error description and compare it to the the error you are looking for such as the email already in use error (in an if statement), and then execute the necessary code you want for that error.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift:**

Make a UiAlertController whos description is error?.localizedDescription.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert) 
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil
```

*You can also add a UIAlertAction which allows your user to dismiss the AlertController*